# JessTab: Can we count all subclass instances?

Tags: protege, jess

I have a class A which consists of two subclasses B and C. Class B has three instances, while C two. Can I write a JessTab rule which will count all implicit instances of A i.e. give me 5?

Mapping class A in Jess:

```
(mapclass http...#A)
```

Rule to count instances which gives me 0 since there are no direct instances of A:

Originally:

```
(defrule countAinstances 
?c <- (accumulate (bind ?count 0) 
(bind ?count (+ ?count 1)) 
?count 
(object (ís-a http...#A))
) 
=> 
(printout t ?c " number of class A instances." crlf))
```

This doesn't count instances of subclasses of A.

Modified version:

```
(defrule countAinstances 
?c <- (accumulate (bind ?count 0) 
(bind ?count (+ ?count 1)) 
?count 
(object (OBJECT ?x&:(instanceof ?x http...#A)))
) 
=> 
(printout t ?c " number of class A instances." crlf))
```

The following error appears:

> Jess reported an error in routine instanceof  while executing
>   (instanceof ?_20_x(0,2,-1) http...#A)     while executing rule LHS (TEQ)
>     while executing rule LHS (TECT).   Message: Class not found:
>   http...#A.   Program text: ( defrule countAinstances ?c <- (
>   accumulate ( bind ?count 0 ) ( bind ?count ( + ?count 1 ) ) ?count (
>   object ( OBJECT ?x & : ( instanceof ?x http...#A ) ) ) ) = > (
>   printout t ?c " number of class A instances." crlf ) )  at line 20.
>
> Nested exception is: http...#A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the object and rely on Jess' own function instanceof, not the protege slot is-a:

```
(object (OBJECT ?x&:(instanceof ?x A)))
```

Use the full class name if A isn't imported.

if you don't have the Java class name, you'll have to test for all classes and subclasses in that pattern, using an (or) function. Rather tedious.

**Later**

Seeing that is-a contains class references that can be compared to class names, this would be the simplest way of writing the rule:

```
defrule countAinstances
?c <- (accumulate (bind ?count 0) 
(bind ?count (+ ?count 1)) 
?count 
(object (is-a ?x&B|C))
      )
=> 
(printout t ?c " number of subclass instances." crlf))
```

Comment: I modified the question to include your proposed alternative

Comment: @Edi Don't you have class names as they are used in Java? This "http...#A" stuff can't be a class name - wrong syntax.

Comment: I have used that for brevity. It's full URL is: [https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/family_example.owl#A] @laune

Comment: That's not a Java class name either. - See my extension to the answer.

Comment: @Edi, don't remove the original question text - otherwise answer and comment exchange become unintellegible. You can add to a question - see my edit of your Q

Comment: Ok I thought it had to be changed

Comment: One cannot use OR within accumulate condition based on our past experience

Comment: You can use an or function in a slot constraint:  `?x&:(or (instanceof ?x A) (instanceof ?x B))`

Comment: With Java classes the same error appears: Class not found. I tried with is-a slot and got the result.

Comment: I woould like to do the calculation automatically i.e. loop in each subclass and count the instances. There is a JessTab command class-subclasses which returns all class subclasses, but cannot loop within it with foreach construct. Any suggestion?

Comment: Normally I'd insert a fact containing the (Java) class and accumulate facts where the object is an instanceof the class (or the is-a slot contains that class). This would give me the fact counts per class.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution-rule is as follows:

```
(defrule countAinstances
?c <- (accumulate (bind ?count 0) 
(bind ?count (+ ?count 1)) 
?count 
(object (is-a ?x&:(or (= ?x B)(= ?x C))))
)
=> 
(printout t ?c " number of subclass instances." crlf))
```

Comment: Can be simplified - see my answer